# Minimization problem in proving Fermat's principle

Tags: mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus

I am trying to prove the Fermat's Principle of least distance, the problem statement goes:

`Minimize[{n1* d1 * Sec[theta1] + n2 * d2 * Sec[theta2], d1 * Tan[theta1]+d2*Tan[theta2]==d},theta1]`

I can't get a solution to this. The good solution should satisfy`n1*Sin[theta1]=n2*Sin[theta2]`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your constraint forces `theta1 -> 
 ConditionalExpression[
  ArcTan[(d - d2 Tan[theta2])/
    d1] + \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]], 
  ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]`

Comment: It is well explained how to proceed here: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph5B/fermat09.pdf

Comment: @DanielHuber: It is not so simple. There is a chance that a critical point is a point of maximum or a saddle point or is outside an interval.

Comment: To investigate what sort of critical point you have, you can use the Hessen matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you try to derive [the law of retraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law). Unfortunately, your notations are

not defined, so I'll use the notations from that Wiki article.

[image]

Without loss of generality we may put $c=1$. We know the quantities $a,b,l,n_1,n_2,$ and $x$ is unknown. The optimization problem to derminate $x$ is formulated as follows.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Minimize[{n1*Sqrt[x^2 + a^2] + n2*Sqrt[b^2 + (l - x)^2], 
n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && l >= 0 && b > 0 && a > 0 && x <= l && x >= 0},  x]
```

Five parameters are too much for `Minimize` and the command is running without any response for hours. However, Mathematica does it for the  specified parameters , e.g.

```
n1 = 1; n2 = 3/2; l = 2; b = 5; a = 1; 
Minimize[{n1*Sqrt[x^2 + a^2] + n2*Sqrt[b^2 + (l - x)^2], n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && l >= 0 && b > 0 && 
x <= l && x >= 0}, x] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.183459, {1/ 2 (2 Sqrt[ 1 + Root[36 - 36 # - 71 #^2 - 20 #^3 + 5 #^4& , 1, 0]^2] +  3 Sqrt[29 - 4 Root[36 - 36 # - 71 #^2 - 20 #^3 + 5 #^4& , 1, 0] + Root[36 - 36 # - 71 #^2 - 20 #^3 + 5 #^4& , 1, 0]^2]), {x ->  Root[36 - 36 # - 71 #^2 - 20 #^3 + 5 #^4& , 1, 0]}}}`.

Now we extract

```
x = x /. x -> Root[36 - 36 # - 71 #^2 - 20 #^3 + 5 #^4 &, 1, 0];
```

and express $\sin \theta_1$ and $\sin \theta_2$ through $a,b,x,l$ (see the linked Wiki article)

```
FullSimplify[x/Sqrt[x^2 + a^2]/(l - x)*Sqrt[(l - x)^2 + b^2]]
```

> `3/2`.

I think Mathematica is able to crack the general case, but it requires a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

One could solve for critical points for the travel time `T` from one point to the other:

```
Block[{d, d1, n1, d2, n2},
 SetAttributes[#, Constant] & /@ {d, d1, n1, d2, n2};
 dT = Dt@{ (* differential of time + distance constraint *)
    d1 n1 Sec[theta1] + d2 n2 Sec[theta2],
    d1 Tan[theta1] + d2 Tan[theta2] - d}
 ]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {d1 n1 Dt[theta1] Sec[theta1] Tan[theta1] + 
>     d2 n2 Dt[theta2] Sec[theta2] Tan[theta2], 
>    d1 Dt[theta1] Sec[theta1]^2 + d2 Dt[theta2] Sec[theta2]^2}
> *)
> ```

```
jacT = CoefficientArrays[ 
    dT, Dt@{theta1, theta2}
    ][[2]];
```

The `Solve` form `sol` may be acceptable as is, but the OP showed an equation `soleq` for the expected solution:

```
sol = jacT //
    Det //
   Simplify //
  Solve[# == 0, Sin@theta1, Reals] &

soleq = sol[[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal //
 Simplify[#, n1 > 0] &
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{Sin[theta1] -> (n2 Sin[theta2])/n1}}  <-- sol
>   n1 Sin[theta1] == n2 Sin[theta2]        <-- soleq
> *)
> ```

Comment: First, a good code is a commented code. Second, your solution is somewhat formal: `d1 = -2;
Block[{d, n1, d2, n2}, SetAttributes[#, Constant] & /@ {d, n1, d2, n2};
  dT = Dt@{(*differential of time+distance constraint*)
     d1 n1 Sec[theta1] + d2 n2 Sec[theta2], 
     d1 Tan[theta1] + d2 Tan[theta2] - d}];jacT = CoefficientArrays[dT, Dt@{theta1, theta2}][[2]];sol = jacT // Det // Simplify // Solve[# == 0, Sin@theta1, Reals]`  produces `{}[2 d2 Sec[theta1] Sec[
   theta2] (-n1 Sec[theta2] Tan[theta1] + n2 Sec[theta1] Tan[theta2])]` . Maybe `{}` indicates that is impossible?

Comment: If we put `d1=2` in the above, the result is the same.

Comment: All that is not so simple. There is a chance that a critical point is a point of maximum or a saddle point or is outside an interval.